# Get only Xml among text file

Tags: c#, xml

I have many files ".txt" files which has usual text and xml tags in the file. The file is really big and quantity of files is really high. So I want just take xml without text. I know that
tags start from `<body>` and ends with `</body>`. I need take just `<body>` and all nested tags in `<body>`

Example of file:

```
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
 <body>
 ...
 </body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
<body>
 ...
</body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
<body>
 ...
</body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
```

I've tried to use `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);`, but I've got an exception:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Since the entire file isn't XML you can't parse it as XML. You'll need to manually parse out the body tags.

Comment: @AlG  through Regex for better performance?

Comment: Little suggestion, read each line, when you hit <body> you are inTag, while inTag extract the xml, when you hit a </body> tag change inTag = false.

Comment: Are you sure the content between `<body>`and `</body>`is well-formed, valid xml?

Comment: Are there any XML specific characters in the rest of the text (like `<`, `>` etc), outside of the `<body>` tags?

Comment: @MattJones no, there are no XML specific tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like code below.  It will work if all the lines start with a "<".  If not we may need to use Regex.

```
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);
            string inputLine = "";
            string str = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputLine.Trim().StartsWith("<"))
                {
                    str += inputLine + "\n";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Definitely ReadLine() without question.  Regex uses lots of memory.  When parsing Regex creates a hierarchy of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not necessarily a good idea you can actually parse this as XML by wrapping it in a single pair of tags as long as you are sure that it is properly delimited (i.e. < as < within the non-XML content etc.) - XML does allow you to have mixed content within an element, that is a combination of data and nested elements.

e.g. the following is valid XML :

```
<FileContent>
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
 <body>
 ...
 </body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
<body>
 ...
</body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
<body>
 ...
</body>

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText

exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
exampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleTextexampleText
</FileContent>
```

So if you just wrap it in a pair of tags you can load it.  You could then access the body elements using XPath.

e.g. something like (untested)

```
public string GetBodyTagContent (string fileContent)
{
    var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("<FileContent>" + fileContent + "</FileContent>");
    return string.Join(",", (from n in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//body") select n.InnerText));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot wrap in single pair of tag

Answer (score 0):

html contains file contents.
resultList would give list of body contents
Short explanation - It matches all text between two body tags. The `*?` at end is non-greedy or lazy quantifier and allows to match multiple body tags instead of text in first `<body>` and last `</body>` tag.

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
Regex regx = new Regex("<body>(?<bodyContents>.*?)</body>", options);
Match matchResult = regx.Match(html);
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
while (matchResult.Success)
{
       var d = matchResult.Groups["bodyContents"].Value;
       resultList.Add(d.Trim());          
       matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

The regex works with specific pattern (text between body tags), however it would fail if body has attributes or html is not properly formed.